# Android - start called in state 1

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm facing trouble with my application, what i want to do is when i click the child of exp list it will play song.
it's clear when start play first song but after stop and I play it again an error display in my logcat.
I don't know how to solve this problem.
please help...

Here's my code:

```
public class BacktrackActivity extends Activity {

     MediaPlayer mp;
     ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
        Context context;
        public ImageButton stop;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.backtrack);

        //    final int[] blues = {R.raw.satch_boogie, R.raw.satch_boogie};
           mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.satch_boogie);

            // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.genre_list);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                }
            });


         expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

         expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choose your " +
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Backtrack",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

      // Listview on child click listener
            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                    mp.start();

                return false;
                }
                }); 
            }

        /*
         * Preparing the list data
         */
        private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("Blues");
            listDataHeader.add("Jazz");
            listDataHeader.add("Rock");
            listDataHeader.add("RnB");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> Blues = new ArrayList<String>();
            Blues.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
            Blues.add("The Godfather");
            Blues.add("The Godfather: Part II");
            Blues.add("Pulp Fiction");
            Blues.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
            Blues.add("The Dark Knight");
            Blues.add("12 Angry Men");

            List<String> Jazz = new ArrayList<String>();
            Jazz.add("The Conjuring");
            Jazz.add("Despicable Me 2");
            Jazz.add("Turbo");
            Jazz.add("Grown Ups 2");
            Jazz.add("Red 2");
            Jazz.add("The Wolverine");

            List<String> Rock = new ArrayList<String>();
            Rock.add("2 Guns");
            Rock.add("The Smurfs 2");
            Rock.add("The Spectacular Now");
            Rock.add("The Canyons");
            Rock.add("Europa Report");

            List<String> RnB = new ArrayList<String>();
            RnB.add("2 Guns");
            RnB.add("The Smurfs 2");
            RnB.add("The Spectacular Now");
            RnB.add("The Canyons");
            RnB.add("Europa Report");

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Blues); // Header, Child data
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Jazz);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Rock);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), RnB);
}
}
```

here's my logcat error

12-04 08:52:54.317: W/Trace(1413): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-04 08:52:54.336: E/MediaPlayer(1413): start called in state 1
12-04 08:52:54.336: E/MediaPlayer(1413): error (-38, 0)
12-04 08:52:54.356: W/Trace(1413): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-04 08:52:54.356: W/Trace(1413): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-04 08:52:54.416: W/Trace(1413): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-04 08:52:54.416: W/Trace(1413): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-04 08:52:54.466: E/MediaPlayer(1413): Error (-38,0)

Comment: Please paste your logcat error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of error happens when you try to call `start()` before `prepare()` is finished. 
Before calling mp.start(); you should make sure that you have already set the `setDataSource()` and prepare() is completed.
In your code by clicking stop, you have reset the media.So before calling mp.start() again you should at least `setDataSource()` again.
IMHO, it worked the first time because you have set the data source ( `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.satch_boogie);` )inside the `onCreate()` method and there is enough time for it to prepared by the time you click the listView child.
Try setDataSource (`MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.satch_boogie);`) anytime you reset it.

Comment: i try but when i type  mp.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.satch_boogie)); at onClick error, "The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)"

Comment: just add  mp = MediaPlayer.create(BacktrackActivity.this, R.raw.satch_boogie); after mp.reset();
Thank you very much.